# Read/Write from/to Hierarchical Object Store - SharePoint 2007

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0, sharepoint-timer-job

I've created a custom timer job which has requires some configurations to run. I'm trying to save the configurations as an `SPPersistedObject` in hierarchical object store.

Hierarchical object store is saved in the SharePoint configuration database and hence I'm getting 'Security Error' while trying to save it with a `SPWebApplication` as the parent.

I've even tried elevating the privileges but it dint help because it is just the application pool account for the current web application and it is not necessary for it to have the access to the SharePoint config database.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found the hierarchical object store (HOS) is stored in the configuration database, not the content database.

If you're running in the context of a site other than the central admin then the user account the application pool uses [may not have permissions to Write to the configuration database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263445%28office.12%29.aspx).

This is a bit of a doozy as you probably won't see this on a developer installation (as you probably won't have it setup with domain level accounts for app pools, only NETWORK SERVICE) and you will only trip up when you get to production.

*Note - Using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges will not change this as that just eleveates from the restricted user account to the application pool account and not the central admin app pool account.*

The article [Managing Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649798.aspx) gives a breakdown of the options and it says about the HOS

> Security model - Users need
>   administrator privileges to access the
>   related SharePoint object (such as
>   SPFarm or SPWebApplication).

For these reasons **I think the HOS is very limited in real world usage and you're better off using the Property Bag Storage model** which can store settings at the Farm/WebApp/Site and List Levels :-

> Advantages - It is probably the most
>   light-weight and easy to use of all
>   the configuration storage options.

There are also reported [performance and stability benefits](http://www.lcbridge.nl/vision/2008/object.htm).

In fact the [MSDN SharePoint Guidance Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649628.aspx) also uses the Property Bag storage for their implementation of a hierarchical **Configuration Manager**.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow the below article that may be help for you 
http://www.bluedoglimited.com/SharePointThoughts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=271

as well a project on codeplex

http://features.codeplex.com/

Comment: 1. I dint say that I'm creating a web part
   2. My application won't be running inside central administration; It could run from any web application 

So is hierarchical object store can only be used from Central Admin?

Comment: I don't get it - are you creating a custom timer job (as indicated in the original post) or are you creating something that will run inside a web application (as indiciated in your comment here)?  It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've a custom application which creates timer jobs based on the user inputs and schedules some long running operations. It is a user interactive applications to schedule tasks. Any other doubts?