# Getting database name and login details during application setup and reading it from the application

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, database-connection, setup-deployment

I've created a SharePoint web part. The web part makes use of a custom database. During installing my web part I get the database name and the login details for accessing the database. I need to read these values given during the installation in my application and connect to the database.

Where I can store/retrieve these values? Since my application resides inside an asp.net web application how easily can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you avoid the SPPersistedObject altogether and store things in the SPPropertyBag at the farm, web app or site level.

More details why in this answer, including links to code samples such as the MSDN - SharePoint Guidance library.

[SO - Read/Write from/to Hierarchical Object Store - SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561976/read-write-from-to-hierarchical-object-store-sharepoint-2007/4562858#4562858)

Comment: Hey Ryan. Yes, I posted that question and I remember your answer. Will never touch HOS again. Got lot of burns already.

Comment: It is a farm level solution. Where can I store the settings then?

Comment: Oh - so you did, sorry I didn't spot that you were the OP on that Q. In Farm level solution you can store in SPFarm.Properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.sppersistedobject.properties.aspx Code samples linked in other answer.

Comment: Yes found that. BTW, Colin was talking about property bag too and not SPPersistedObject :).

Answer (score 1):

A SharePoint `SPWebApplication` (well actually, it's base `SPPersistedObject`) has a `Properties` property (it's a PropertyBag / HashTable), in which you can store values. I suggest storing your connection data in there.